# Light dims when plugged in, doesn't dim when hard wired to feed

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I have a peculiar situation.  My LED light is fully dimmable down to 10% per manufacturer spec ([this light](http://bit.ly/2nbxT3w)).  To test its function, I hardwired the light to a plug (like this [Plug](http://bit.ly/2nbg6s4)) via a dimmer switch ([this](http://bit.ly/2FipWQt) ), and plugged into a wall receptacle.  It dimmed nicely. So I then hardwired the switch to a 15amp feed in a box.  The light turns on and off, but doesn't dim.  What could be the cause?

Comment: The first cause could be that you hard-wired the switch incorrectly.  Pictures of the wiring job are usually helpful for questions like this.

Comment: You also may have accidentally let the [magic smoke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) out of the dimmer.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  The black wire from the light fixture is connected to the red screw.  And the black wire from the panel is connected to the black screw.